# Wine will not use my GPU

Tags: 12.04, drivers, wine, games, amd-graphics

I have an AMD A8 CPU/APU running with an ATI 6670 (or something like that). I have turned off the integrated graphics card and I am just running with the 6670. The thing is I have installed Steam via Wine so I can play my games that aren't supported by the Linux version. I downloaded Counter Strike Global Offensive to play and I get an error message saying:

```
Your graphics hardware does not support all features (CSM) needed to run this game.
```

The part that gets me is that the "driver name" is my ATI Radeon HD 3200 which is my APU. I do not know how to get around this.

I am currently installing legacy drivers to see if that helps.

Comment: The legacy driver didn't work.

Comment: I am going to try installing a different game. Still using Steam via wine. Will update as soon as the game installs.

Answer (score 0):

[Try installing bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation)

Post that, start the bumblebee server.

Launch the application using optirun

"optirun wine app.exe"

Worked for me. Hope it helps.